# Customizing Laravel Registration Validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm retouching `validator()` method which is created by `php artisan auth` command. It looks like this:

```
protected function custom_validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6',
        'cell_phone' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
}
```

And here is my own `create()` method:

```
public function custom_create(Request $request)
{
    $this->custom_validator($request->all())->validate();
    dd('validation done ...');
}
```

It works as expected and all fine.

---

**My question:** What's `->validate()` in `custom_create()` method? As I said, it works and I've written it according to the Laravel default. But I don't understand it.

I believe this is enough `$this->custom_validator($request->all())`. It calls `custom_validator()` method which is in the same class. So what's `->validate()`? Where is it come from?

Comment: look this file `Illuminate\Validation\Validator.php`

Comment: I don't find `Illuminate` directory in the root of project.

Comment: `vendor\laravel\framework\src\`

Comment: `Validator::make` gives you a validator instance which gives the instance access to https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->validate()` is for automatic redirection if validation fails.

From Docs

[**Automatic Redirection**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#automatic-redirection)

> If you would like to create a validator instance
>   manually but still take advantage of the automatic redirection offered
>   by the requests's validate method, you may call the validate method on
>   an existing validator instance. If validation fails, the user will
>   automatically be redirected or, in the case of an AJAX request, a JSON
>   response will be returned:

And the syntax is

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'body' => 'required',
])->validate();
```

In your case you are sending `Validator` instance and calling `validate()` after.

Answer (score 1):

add these lines

```
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use lluminate\Support\Collection;
```